# Use listbox to modify textbox control for comments

Tags: forms, ms-access, where-clause

Objective: To use a listbox to find a help topic then automatically use code to find the correlated topic comment in relation to user selection. Basically which property does the textbox need to requery to setup the selected record? Perhaps this would que through the related records, so if the ID reads 2 then field from the comment box in record 2 would be displayed.

**This is pseudocode:**

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
Dim myTopic As String
myTopic = "Select * from FormsHelpTable where ([ID] = " & Me.List35 & ")"
Me.Comment.{property to find record/related text} = myTopic
Me.Comment.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
Dim myTopic As String
myTopic = "Select * from FormsHelpTable where ([ID] = " & Me.List35 & ")"
Me.Form.RecordSource = myTopic
Me.Comment.Requery
End Sub
```

Instead of trying to requery or update the individual textbox object, just update the current form RecordSource to the selection.